# Phonegap build - Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am developing a test app in PhoneGap build. Currently I'm trying to redirect to a page when the app loads. But when I tried to do that, it is not redirecting, instead staying in *index.html* page only. I am using [TestObject](https://testobject.com/) for testing the app.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function init() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
            }

            function onDeviceReady() {
                alert("Device is ready");
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />
        Hai welcome to my app
    </body>
</html>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.mydomain.mobileApp"
        versionCode = "1" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is Android only -->
    <!-- version is in major.minor.patch format --> 
    <name>My App</name>

    <description>
        An example for phonegap build app which wont show up in the playstore. 
    </description>

    <author href="https://YourWebsite.com" email="yourEmail@goesHere.com">
        Name Of The Author
    </author>

</widget>
```

When I test this in browser, on clicking button it will redirect to http://google.com. But when I upload the apk (build from phonebuild) and upload to TestObject, button is coming. But on clicking it nothing happens. When I test the app,I'm getting like this.

[image]

Can anyone help me to find the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://phonegap.com/getstarted/ Please follow the tutorials and try to specify your question.

Comment: are you working using phonegap-cli or phonegap-app-desktop ?

Comment: @HassanALi..I'm using phonegap build..

Comment: I have created this index.html and config.xml file and uploaded to phonegap build..Then downloaded the apk file from build and is testing in TestObject..I'm referring this link http://pointdeveloper.com/create-config-xml-file-phonegap-build-scratch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `phonegap.js` in `head` section of HTML file and do not make the click event handler inline. Register the event handler in `script` part. And also make sure you have included `whitelist` plugin. Try following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFun(){
            document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
            location.href='http://google.com';
            });
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFun()">
        <button id="myBtn">Go to Google</button>
        Hai welcome to my app
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried only this code.Is any other code is there?

Comment: I tried with your code replacing my code..Also I tried with adding `window.location` in button click function. That also didn't worked..

Comment: Have you added `whitelist` plugin ?If not add it.

Comment: @Homen..I'm using phonegap build not phonegap cli or desktop app. So do I need to install whitelist plugin?

Comment: yes you need.You can use this reference http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/plugins/  .BDW phonegap cli or desktop app is the easiest way.

Comment: @homen..Thankyou so much..I included whitelist plugin in config.xml and it is working fine now..

Comment: Hi Jenz, @Homen , sorry to bring up a dead thread, but could someone share with me how to include the whitelist plugin in config.xml? thanks.

Comment: Hi @HarveyFletcher , check in this documentation http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/plugins/  . Here you will get some sample.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include cordova in your application

and try this one as well

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
      alert("Device ready Fire");
 },true);
```